# Incrementing a number each time it replaces a string

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

So I working with a script that looks like this. It works just fine the only issue is that it is counting the line numbers and I just wanted it to replace num each time with 1 2 3 4 etc insted it is looking like this 5 20 25 etc and that is because it seems to be counting and incremnting $c for each line not each time it replaces the string num.

```
$c=0
(Get-Content C:\Users\H\Desktop\3.txt) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "num", $((++$c))}  | 
Out-File C:\Users\H\Desktop\4.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
$c = [ref] 0
$text = Get-Content 'C:\Users\H\Desktop\3.txt' -Raw
[regex]::Replace( $text, 'num', { (++$c.Value) } ) |
    Set-Content 'C:\Users\H\Desktop\4.txt'

# With PowerShell 6+ you could write:
# (Get-Content 'C:\Users\H\Desktop\3.txt' -Raw) -replace 'num', { (++$c.Value) } |
#    Set-Content 'C:\Users\H\Desktop\4.txt'
```

Copy-pastable demo:

```sh
$text = @'
num foo num
bar num bar
num baz num
'@ 

$c = [ref] 0
[regex]::Replace( $text, 'num', { (++$c.Value) } )

# With PowerShell 6+ you could write:
# $text -replace 'num', { (++$c.Value) }
```

**Output:**

```text
1 foo 2
bar 3 bar
4 baz 5
```

**Explanation:**

- Use a reference type ([`[ref]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-7.2#references-and-scopes)) variable instead of a plain variable. The scriptblock passed to [`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) or [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-a-script-block) (PS 6+ only) runs in a *child scope*, so it can't modify variables from the parent scope *directly*. You *can* modify the *members* of a reference type, so this is why the `[ref]` trick works. Instead of `[ref]` you could also use a `[PSCustomObject]` or a `[Hashtable]` (which are both reference types) with a counter member.
- The parenthesis around the expression `++$c.Value` are required to *output* the value of the expression, which doesn't produce output by default. You already had that, I'm just explaining it for other visitors.
- Using `Get-Content` with parameter `-Raw` can be faster, because the file's content gets output as a single multiline string instead of splitting it up into one string per line, at the expense of requiring more memory.

**As for what you have tried:**

> ```
> $_ -replace "num", $((++$c))
> ```

You are passing an *expression* instead of a *script block* as the RHS argument to the `-replace` operator. Furthermore, a script block argument for the `-replace` operator is only supported beginning with PowerShell 6. For older versions you have to use the .NET function `[Regex]::Replace`.

This expression is evaluated once for each iteration of the `ForEach-Object` "loop", *before* the `-replace` operator is evaluated. So you are effectively just counting the lines of the file, not the number of occurences of the pattern.

Only a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2)'s execution can be *delayed*. It doesn't get called immediately in the place where you define it<sup>1</sup>, but when the function or operator that has a `[ScriptBlock]` parameter decides to call it, possibly multiple times as happens when the pattern has multiple matches. To define a script block, use `{}` as I did in my sample at the beginning.

---

<sup>[1] Unless you use the call or dot source operator, e.g. `&{'foo'}`</sup>

Comment: The above code when applying it acutallly replaces each instance of num with this string . (++$c.Value) I was not trying to do that and instead increment $c each time it replaces the string num and output to a 4.txt

Comment: @Sarash It looks like you are using PowerShell 5.1, where the `-replace` operator doesn't support a script block.  This requires PS 6+, but a workaround for PS 5.1 is possible. Just give me a few minutes...

Comment: Yeah, I am on 5.1 thanks for the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Sarash Updated solution for 5.1.

Comment: @Sarash Glad to be helpful.